# Set url for GraphApi B2C login

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I need to query the Graph API to get the username in the claims. 
I've implemented something based on what I've found on the net, but I keep getting 403 Forbidden, from Graph API.
Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

This is my code:

```
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "clienSecret";
var tenant = "tenantName";
var userObjectId = claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(i => i.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").FirstOrDefault().Value;

var aadGraphVersion = "api-version=1.6";
var query = "/users/" + userObjectId;

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);

// The ClientCredential is where you pass in your client_id and client_secret, which are 
// provided to Azure AD in order to receive an access_token using the app's identity.
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

    // First, use ADAL to acquire a token using the app's identity (the credential)
  // The first parameter is the resource we want an access_token for; in this case, the Graph API.
    AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);

    // For B2C user management, be sure to use the Azure AD Graph API for now.
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

    //var url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + "/users/" + userObjectId + "/?api-version=1.6";

    //var url = graphResource + "tenant" + "/users/" + userObjectId + "/?api-version=1.6";
    string url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + "/users/" + userObjectId +  "?" + aadGraphVersion;
    //url += "&" + query;

    // Append the access token for the Graph API to the Authorization header of the request, using the Bearer scheme.
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

     if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
          string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
          throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
     }
```

I think I have a problem with the `URL` that is not set correctly. The token is correct, I got it ok with the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I do think it is an issue with the URL.  You are getting this error as you have provided user read permissions to your registered application.  Please make sure that -

1. You go to Application registrations menu on your tenant
2. Select "Required Permissions" menu and click on **Windows Azure Active Directory**
3. In the "Enable Access" menu select "Read Directory Data" permissions under Application Permissions section and click save.
4. Once saved on "Required Permissions" menu click on "Grant Permissions" button to provide the consent.

You may need to select other options like "Read and Write Directory Data" if you wish to provide your application to create/update/delete users.